# lost data after changing variables in php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i so confused.. i have ajax code that will throw the value of the select options, this the code:

```
  $('#media-select').on('change',function(){
                var dt = $(this).val();
                alert('media-select='+dt);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {media : dt},
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/uploads/load'); ?>",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#result-media-uploader').load(url);
                    }
                });
            });
```

than the output is nothing, after i checked, that is wrong on server cause the data is an array.. this the output from the print_r();

```
Array( [media] => document)
```

this the full code in server..

```
if(!empty($this->input->post()))
        {
            $media = $this->input->post();
            $data['bug'] = print_r($media);
            $data['file'] = $this->db->where('post_type','attachment')->where('post_mine_type',$media)->get('cs_posts')->result();
            $this->renderblank('admin/pages/uploads/uploads_load',$data);

        }else{

            $data['bug'] = var_dump($media);
            $data['file'] = $this->db->where('post_type','attachment')->where('post_mine_type','image')->order_by('id','DESC')->get('cs_posts')->result();
            $this->renderblank('admin/pages/uploads/uploads_load',$data);
        }
```

so, i fix the code, i change variable $media..

```
$media = $this->input->post('media'); //before change: $media = $this->input->post();
```

please look the line..

after i fix, data was sended from ajax but the output is NULL. if i dont change the $media, i get the data, but if i change i lost the data.. please help me, thats make me confused.. thanks in advance..!

Comment: `$('#result-media-uploader').load(url);` should be `$('#result-media-uploader').html(data);` in success callback

Comment: i have uploads_load that output is html code with value from database..